# Parse and remove HTML tags using Google Refine/OpenRefine & Jsoup/BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, jsoup, magmi, openrefine

I use Google Refine for dealing with messy product data sheets in order to format them for upload into Magento stores using Magmi/Dataflow profiles. I am still using Google Refine 2.5 as it is the latest stable release.

The descriptions from supplier datasheets are often filled with binary characters and messy HTML that I need to manipulate and re-format en masse.

I know I can use some combination of GREL / Python / Jsoup to accomplish my task, but I'm having trouble with the syntax moving in an out of different languages.

My data looks like the following:

`Some product data here. <ul><li>Bullet one <li> Bullet two</ul> <br /> Some other product data here. <span id="product-image><img src="image.png"></span>`

Using the following snippet:`value.parseHtml().select("img").toString()`
I am able to parse the image tags I want, but I'm unable to remove/replace these tags using the `replace()` function in GREL. I tried to add the expression into the first string of the replace function like: `value.replace(/value.parseHtml().select("img").toString()/, "")` and other similar functions to no avail.

For my current project I need to: 1) remove all `<img>, <div>, <p> and <span>` tags, plus 2) parse and separate YouTube video links into a separate column.

Can someone please help me with the syntax / cook me up a function to accomplish this task (preferably with an explanation of the syntax)?

Comment: Can you provide a real snippet of the HTML code you are trying to parse, or the link the the page. That will help to craft the JSON code.

Comment: `<ul>  <li>Excellent quality, reliable socket.</li>  <li>UL listed component.</li>  <li>Rotate lamp 90° to lock in place.</li>  <li>Purchase components a la carte.</li>  <li>Two covers required for set.</li> </ul> <img alt=" style="width: 62px;" src="http://sunlightsupply.s3.amazonaws.com/images/icon/product/logo_culus.gif" /><br /> `

Comment: And also `<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AQFT4QWBEo" rel="prettyPhoto" shape="rect"><img alt=" src="http://sunlightsupply.s3.amazonaws.com/images/icon/product/WatchVideo.gif" complete="complete" /></a> <br /> <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>DESIGNED FOR HEATING/COOLING WITH OUTSIDE TEMPERATURES RANGING FROM 5<sup>°</sup> TO 105<sup>°</sup> F.<br /> </strong><strong>USE OF UNIT OUTSIDE OF THESE TEMPERATURE RANGES IS NOT RECOMMENDED.<br /> IMPROPER USAGE RELATING TO OUTSIDE TEMPERATURE IS NOT COVERED UNDER WARRANTY.</strong></p> <ul>`

Comment: This description also includes a `<sup>` tag I've never seen before that also needs to be removed. I can link to the whole product .csv if necessary. Thanks for the help

Comment: `<sup>` tags are valid html tags.  It's used for superscript text (text that appears at the top of the line in smaller letters).

Comment: Also, you should focus on using a regex statement that removes all tags, EX anything that's contained within brackets `<>` instead of trying to eliminate each one individually.

Comment: I meant I hadn't seen the <sup> tags before, not that they were invalid. This brings my other point -- there are some tags I WANT in the data, particularly list formatting and a few other basics that made removing all HTML impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove Tag

If you want to just replace the tag, there is no need to use `parsHtml()`. Simply do `value.replace('<img','')` to remove all image related tag. `value.replace('<div>','').replace('</div>','')` for all the `<div>`

### Extract Images

`value.parseHtml().select("img").toString()` select the tag **and its content**. Using your example it will returns:

`<img alt=" style=" width:="" 62px="" src="http://sunlightsupply.s3.amazonaws.com/images/icon/product/logo_culus.gif" />`

and

`<img alt=" src=" http:="" sunlightsupply="" s3="" amazonaws="" com="" images="" icon="" product="" watchvideo="" gif="" complete="complete" />`

### Extract YouTube Link

The following GREL `value.split('href=')[1].split('"')[0]` will extract all links.

You can store them in a new column an remove all links who doesn't contains youtube.com using a custom facet with `value.contains('youtube.com')`

Comment: Using value.replace('<img','') will not replace the entire tag. What about the '/>" at the end? Or in some cases just ">". Not to mention, the 'src="..."' attribute name and value pair.

Comment: the `parseHtml()` take care of that initially. I also turn my initial stackoverflow answer into a blog post if you are interested to dig more on this topic: http://googlerefine.blogspot.com/2015/02/parsing-and-extracting-html-tag-and.html

Comment: But you say "there is no need to use parseHtml()". The value.replace('<img', '') does not replace the full tag markup. It's fine for <div> and </div> since the full tags are specified, but not '<img'. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
value.replace(/<[^>]*>/,"")
```

This will remove all HTML tags, everything within <...>

Comment: As you're answering a 7 year old question that already has an accepted answer, some additional commentary might be helpful to explain your answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 